# Create an HTML table where text overflows across rows within a column

Tags: html, css

I need to create a table (or something that is rendered like a table; it's meant to be printed and I don't care what it is semantically) where the text flows automatically from one row to the next within the same column. Also, the columns need to have a pre-determined width, and there must be a pre-determined number of rows (with extra empty rows if needed).

Example:

[image]

The reason behind this, in case you're wondering, is that it's meant to emulate text that's hand-written into a printed form that looks like the table above, only empty.

How would you do this?